# Process multiple csv files and store data in separate text files (removing spaces and new lines) using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am struggling to get this script work.

I am trying to process all csv files (one at a time) using powershell and save each csv file as a separate text file.

In the text file, i am looking to have all the IP's in a single line separated by a comma (for example 192.168.73.44,192.168.75.224,192.168.76.45,192.168.77.105,192.168.77.237,192.168.78.33,192.168.78.92)

So this script should extract each ipv4address column value from a particular csv file and add a comma "," after every IP address and append all the IP's from that particular csv to a text file.

My script is processing the csv's and generating the text files but it is only writing the first IP found in csv to a text file.

## Could you please help me out here?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\*.csv | Foreach-Object {

  $basename = $_.Name

  $detail = import-csv $_ 

 foreach ($csv in $detail) { 

 $Outputs =@()
 $field = $csv.ipv4address

 $field = $field + ","
 $Outputs +=$field 

 } 

$Outputs | Out-File "C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$basename.txt"

$regexA = "(\s,)"

$regexB = "\s" 

(Get-Content C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$basename.txt | Out-String) -replace $regexA,' ' -replace "`r?`n(?!`r?`n)"  -join ' ' -replace $regexB, ''|

Set-Content C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$basename.txt

$b = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$basename.txt
@(ForEach ($a in $b) {$a.Replace(' ', '')}) > C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$basename.txt
}
```

[IPs.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kY3VIwMiBauESgtfm0YE9QZyqkPXWpXW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you share the CSV file, for us to have some sample data to work with?

Comment: Hi Motz, I have uploaded csv on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kY3VIwMiBauESgtfm0YE9QZyqkPXWpXW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your CSV, I figured this would just be easier to re-write. It is a lot easier to follow than what you were doing.

```
$skips = $null, '', ' '
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\*.csv| ForEach-Object {
    $csv = import-csv $_.FullName
    $IPArray = @()
    Foreach($ip in $csv) {
        if(!($ip.ipv4address -in $skips)) {
            $IPArray += $ip.ipv4address
        }
    }
    $IPArray -join ','| Out-File C:\Temp\Qualys\All\AssetGroups\Textfiles\$($_.BaseName).txt
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, tried this but it still gives the same result.

Comment: Re-wrote the entire thing, works on my end now, based on the CSV you provided.

Comment: Hi Drew, This works perfect, just one thing, if csv has some blank values in IP column the end result will look like something as below: is there a way we can remove null values in the same code you provided? 10.190.83.208,10.190.54.237,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,10.190.174.125,10.190.175.210 so the result looks something like 10.190.83.208,10.190.54.237,10.190.174.125,10.190.175.210

Comment: @Analyst I have updated the code for you. Just got back into work so sorry for the delay.

Comment: Awesome Drew, Thanks so much